# Why and when would you use a .NET framework data type?

Tags: c#, .net, data-types

I've seen an increasing trend of people submitting code to SO that includes the use of [.NET Framework data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfa3fa08(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1).

I understand that the .NET Framework has its own data types (like `Int16`, `Int32`, `Boolean`, etc) that map to the appropriate data type in the language you are using (like C#). But why use that over the language-specific data type? **Is there a specific reason to do this or certain case where using a .NET Framework data type would be more advantageous than a language-specific data type?**

Comment: When you're sad, use `int`, because it is *dark* blue. When you are light and happy, use `Int32`, because it is _light_ blue!

Comment: ... when you are ANGRY, use `IntThatDoesNotExist`, because it will be black like your soul and underlined in angry red squiggles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are not two distinct, different types - `System.String` and `string` are not *equivalent* types, they are simply two aliases to the *same* type.

The choice of using one or the other is thus entirely stylistic. One project or programmer might say "`int` is the native C# term. It's short and clear and intuitive, and thus I will always use it". Another might say "`Int32` is universal and unambiguous. It means the same whether I'm using C# or VB or F# and anyone reading it knows what it means without having to know the specific language in question".

Both are valid. Both might be more useful in different contexts (a pure C# project vs. a mixed-language project), but they map to the same IL, the same machine code, the same runtime in the end.

Comment: So in reality then, the "language-specific" type (for lack of a better term) is just an alias; the ".NET Framework type" **is** the type right?

Comment: @Sylverac Yes. As long as C# is running on top of the .NET framework, of course.